# Why i see cordova android emulator error?

Tags: cordova, vue.js

I use corodva + vueJs framework. I instll Android Studio. I run command

```
cordova emulate android
```

end see error

```
    D:\PROJECTS\PLANSTER\PRODUCTIONS\MOBILE\planster\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Nil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Users\Nil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Users\Nil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

how solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have any emulators created / running. Follow the documentation below to create one ('Create an AVD' section), and start it up before running `cordova emulate android`:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

You can check your running emulators and devices using `adb devices`. This will show you the available devices that you can deploy to.